# How to make a horizontal ScrollView in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, winui-3, winui

I'm experienced with c#, however, I'm new to developing Windows programs and XAML, I've been trying to make a horizontal ScrollView but couldn't find a solution on the internet whatsoever. If anyone has any idea on how to make it work I'd be thankful.
I'm working on a WinUi 3 project btw.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a ScrollViewer like this:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <!--Put the content you want to scroll here-->
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but then I can't make it snap to position (stop scrolling) on every item

Comment: Why? You could use the viewchangedevent and every time the horizontalscrollposition has changed for example 10 to the old value you could disable scrolling or do anything else.

Comment: True, but it wouldn't be smooth. I believe there should be a straightforward solution I just can't find it!

Comment: Which goal do you want to archive with this? Maybe there is a different control.

Comment: I want to make a horizontal scroll menu that snaps to position while scrolling, and as you can see I'm soo new to all of this lol so if you could help me it'd be much appreciated

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/pivot You can also check out the WinUi 3 Controls Gallery. There is every control listed and you can test it out